# close-group problem java RTFEditorKit

Tags: java, rtf

I am using a java RTFEditorKit that converts RTF to text most of the time.   Some times, I will encounter a file where instead of the conversion taking place, I get the following:

java.io.IOException:  Too many close-groups in RTF text
   at javax.swing.rtf.RTFParser.write(Unknown Source)

I've looked around the internet but don't see a ready solution to this problem.

Anybody else seen this and know what to do?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: When you look at the code for the RTFEditorKit, there is a comment that says "Start End Groups are not synchronized".    I don't know if that means anything to anyone. But there it is, just in case.

Comment: The RTFEditor code has a comment where this exception is thrown "Start End Groups are not synchronized."   I don't know if this adds clarity to the situation but that is what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code, this exception will be thrown if you have more closing braces than opening braces in your RTF. Sounds like your file is probably malformed.

Here is the code which throws the Exception:

```
else if(ch == '}') {
  if (currentCharacters.length() > 0) {
    handleText(currentCharacters.toString());
    currentCharacters = new StringBuffer();
  }
  if (level == 0)
    throw new IOException("Too many close-groups in RTF text");
  endgroup();
  level --;
}
```